# Using url in a command adds unwanted spaces

Tags: macros, packages, urls

With url-Package imported like this

```
\usepackage[obeyspaces, hyphens]{url}
```

defining a command like this

```
\newcommand{\dirpath}[1]{{\url{#1}}}
```

will when used like this

```
\dirpath{Documents\BliBla\bludsdus\dssdsd}
```

produce spaces in the output:

[image: spaces in output]

For comparison:

```
\dirpath{Documents\BliBla\bludsdus\dssdsd}\linebreak\linebreak
\url{Documents\BliBla\bludsdus\dssdsd}
```

[image]

How can one prevent these spaces to be added? I want to use the command to define how to format directory paths in my document.

Comment: `\newcommand{\dirpath}{\url}` But there's already `\path`.

Comment: This works for this specific replacement of the name for the command, but i actually want to surround the url part with for example quotes or something similar, like `\newcommand{\dirpath}[1]{"\url{#1}"}`, `\newcommand{\dirpath}{"\ url "}` doesnt work here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\DeclareUrlCommand` and specify before and after text for the url via `\UrlLeft` and `\UrlRight`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[obeyspaces, hyphens]{url}

\DeclareUrlCommand{\dirpath}{\def\UrlLeft{\textrm{``}}\def\UrlRight{\textrm{''}}}

\begin{document}

\dirpath{Documents\BliBla\bludsdus\dssdsd}

\end{document}
```